Create a table with \newcommand where the values are input as the argument?
I would like to create \newcommand function whose arguments would populate a table.
As an example, my idea is to create something like the following code, where, to populate a Table, I would use a custom function called \testRow, and the arguments of this function (#1 and #2) would be the values per se.
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
     \hline
     \testRow{Cell1-1}{Cell1-2}\\
     \hline
\end{tblr}

with
\newcommand{\testRow}[2]{#1 & #2}

So, this code would be analogous to
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
     \hline
     Cell1-1 & Cell1-2\\
     \hline
\end{tblr}

Problem: the reserved symbol & cannot be properly used inside the argument, as I get the error

"Misplaced alignment tab character &. \testRow #1#2-> #1 &
#2  l.12     \end
{tblr}"

I am a TeX enthusiast and I know there may be better/sophisticated solutions to my problem. When researching for a solution, I entered the rabbit hole and some suggestions that I found (similar to my problem) implied using the xparse package: \newcommand with multiple arguments that generates a table. However, the documentation of xparse is quite obscure to me and I feel lost on creating the table/function that I have in mind.
A snippet of the code that can be tested is the following:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\testRow}[2]{#1 & #2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
     \hline
     \testRow{Cell1-1}{Cell1-2}\\
     \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

Any help would be much appreciated. KR,

please provide a complete minimal example which produces the error or compiles to the output you want help with.

Your example works. Show another example, where you have the described problem.

Yes of course. I am using LuaLatex and the tabular package. The error that I get is the following: "Misplaced alignment tab character &." I just found out that the original question that I asked was my scenario with too many layers of simplification. In fact, the original question was perfectly fine without giving me an error. I will update the question with the scenario that I actually have that creates the error of misplaced tab character.

& can be used in \newcommand just as you show, the expansion would work in a standard tabular the issue is dpecific to tblr but you should provide a test document

Thanks for all the feedback. I updated a small MWE where the error can be tested.

Even though using \testrow{a}{b}instead of a & b is clumsier, I wanted to do it in order to encapsulate functions. The underlying idea I had in mind was to create a table using a \newcommand, in which the arguments would enter another function that would rearrange them by columns. Also, I thought about this because I am creating a template for my working colleagues (not familiar with Latex). Thus, leaving a final product without much room to improv would be crucial (I thought that filling spaces inside { } would be easier for them than having to type many & manually).

I'm not sure why you would want this particular command, so I fear this may not address your actual need, but this answers the question as asked.
tblr parses the content of the environment and so needs to see the & and \\ explicitly. Hence, to use \testRow{}{} inside the environment, we need to expand it before tblr sees it. Fortunately, tabularray provides facilities for ensuring expansion prior to parsing.
The expand key can be used in tblr's options to tell tblr that a command should be pre-expanded. So we just need to add expand=\testRow for the code to work as intended.
\begin{tblr}[expand=\testRow]{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \testRow{Cell1-1}{Cell1-2}\\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

Complete example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand \testRow[2]{#1 & #2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  Cell1-1 & Cell1-2 \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\testRow]{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \testRow{Cell1-1}{Cell1-2}\\
  \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for your response. I did not know about the parsing of tblr (I also feel fortunate such an easy solution could be obtained from this package, even though I spent all afternoon trying different things/researching in Stackexchange). Your answer fulfills my needs 100%. It is true that this solution is a little bit bizarre, but it gets the "thing" done. In particular, I thought about this implementation because I believe it would simplify the template for my coworkers. I guess I must learn much more TeX to not create such clumsy solutions in the future.

I also found this post link in which they answered about the expand key to solve a similar issue. Even though I encountered that post at the beginning of my research, I did not understand it as clear as it is explained in this answer. Thanks again,
